# Modal de bootstrap no muestra su contenido correspondiente utilizando CodeIgniter

Tags: php, bootstrap, codeigniter

**Situación:**

Tengo la siguiente vista en `CodeIgniter` que muestra una tabla con usuarios, uno de los campos de cada usuario es la opción "Editar", que al pulsar sobre ella abre un modal en el que se pueden modificar los campos del usuario, pero en este caso, para simplificar, muestra el nombre del usuario correspondiente:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nick</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Correo</th>
        <th>Fecha de registro</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    foreach ($users as $usr) { //Comienzo del foreach
    ?>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $usr['id']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $usr['nick']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $usr['nombre'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $usr['apellidos'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $usr['email'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo date_format(new DateTime($usr['fecha_registro']), 'd/m/Y'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo botonEstado($usr['estado']); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <div id="modalEdit" class="modal fade">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Editando los campos de <?php echo  $usr['nick']; ?></h4>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal -->
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?><!-- Aquí termina el foreach -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema:**

Todos los datos de la tabla se muestran de la manera esperada, sin embargo, al hacer click sobre "Editar" me muestra siempre el nombre del mismo usuario (el primero del loop)

¿Qué puede estar saliendo mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es el id, en el atributo dataTarget estás usando un selector de id, en este caso `#modalEdit`:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit">
```

Por consiguiente siempre se mostrará el mismo modal, el primero, pues solo puede (debe) haber un elemento con dicho id en todo el documento:

```
<div id="modalEdit" class="modal fade">
```

---

Solución rápida:

Agrega como sufijo al id del elemento, el id del usuario, y tambièn al selector en data-target, algo así:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="Editar" data-target="#modalEdit<?php echo $usr['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" >

<div id="modalEdit<?php echo $usr['id']; ?>" class="modal fade">
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de que sea el problema (sería bueno ver el código html generado), pero me parece que el cierre del loop está en el lugar incorrecto. Cada iteración debería corresponder a una fila de la tabla, entonces el `foreach` debería terminar después del `</tr>`.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero aun así el resultado es el mismo, adjunto en la pregunta un pantallazo de como se muestra la tabla por sí sirve de algo. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: inspecciona el códiugo html generado (es lo que hay que hacer siempre en estos casos), y verifica que cada string "Editando los campos de..." vaya seguido de un nombre de usuario distinto.